# PHP: How to find difference in two multidimensional arrays on spacific key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-difference

I have two multidimensional array and I want find diffrnece between this two arrays but how to get diffrnece based on this key `subscription_plan_id`.

I have used this: `$result = array_diff_assoc($arr1, $arr2);` but getting this errors:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/sitename/application/models/xxx_model.php on line 122

Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/sitename/application/models/xxx_model.php on line 122

Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/sitename/application/models/xxx_model.php on line 122

Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/sitename/application/models/xxx_model.php on line 122
```

**Array results:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [subscription_plan_id] => 13
            [plan_month] => 1
            [start_date] => 2015-03-13
            [end_date] => 2015-04-12
            [s_start_date] => 2015-02-12 09:29:33
            [s_subscription_id] => 70
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [subscription_plan_id] => 2
            [plan_month] => 1
            [start_date] => 2015-03-13
            [end_date] => 2015-04-12
            [s_start_date] => 2015-02-12 09:26:50
            [s_subscription_id] => 69
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [subscription_plan_id] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [subscription_plan_id] => 13
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [subscription_plan_id] => 36
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [subscription_plan_id] => 39
        )

)
```

**I want this result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [subscription_plan_id] => 36
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [subscription_plan_id] => 39
        )

)
```

Answer (score -1):

I have tried with [array_diff_key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php) and its working great with your example code.

Try this code:

```
$arr1 = array
    (
        array('subscription_plan_id' => '13', 'plan_month' => '1', 'start_date' => '2015-03-13', 'end_date' => '2015-04-12', 's_start_date' => '2015-02-12 09:29:33', 's_subscription_id' => '70'),
        array('subscription_plan_id' => '2', 'plan_month' => '1', 'start_date' => '2015-03-13', 'end_date' => '2015-04-12', 's_start_date' => '2015-02-12 09:26:50', 's_subscription_id' => '69')
    );

    $arr2 = array
    (
        array('subscription_plan_id' => '2'),
        array('subscription_plan_id' => '13'),
        array('subscription_plan_id' => '36'),
        array('subscription_plan_id' => '39')
    );

    $diff = array_diff_key($arr2, $arr1);

    echo "<pre>";
        print_r($diff);
    echo "</pre>";
```